# Terminated due to signal 9 when i pressing 1 time Home button in middle of background tasks (using GCD) in iOS app

Tags: ios, background-thread

I want to index the part of content through background thread each time the user run the app, but when i pressing 1 time Home button in middle of background task and app goes to background , this message i received : "Terminated due to signal 9".
i want to index part of content that is possible when app is in foreground mode but in background thread without crashing the app.
My main problem is why the app killed through middle of task running in background thread, even that task will be only print string in console!
how should i handle this scenario?

Comment: Sounds that App uses too much CPU time or memory, then System killed it.

Comment: @YunCHEN  each time i index only part of content for example in scale of 320000 word, i index only 500 word, but through indexing each 500 word, when i press Home, it killed..

Comment: Provide the source code for indexing, maybe we can find a certain problem, or improve the performance.

Comment: Did you try using `UIBackgroundTask` as noted below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to start a background task and end it when you are done with your work something like this

```
var bgTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?
```

Add bgTask as your objects property and then

```
let application = UIApplication.shared

bgTask = application.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "name", expirationHandler: {
    self.endBackgroundTask()
})

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {[weak self] in
    //do your stuff here

    self?.endBackgroundTask()
}
```

Add endBackgroundTask() method

```
func endBackgroundTask() {
    if bgTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
        UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(bgTask!)
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    }
}
```

You can read more about this here

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html